# Can test_ids config as blocks allow checks to test metadata?

Tags: origen-sdk

I see that the Origen test_ids gem allows users to specify blocks as a config.

```
TestIds.configure :final_test do |config|
  config.numbers do |bin, softbin|
    (softbin * 10) + bin 
  end
end
```

Is it possible to reference any of the metadata passed to the test?  For example, here are some test insertions in my flow file:

```
func :mytest, mode: :chain
func :mytest, mode: :jtag
```

Here is what I would like to do in the TestIds config:

```
TestIds.configure :final_test do |config|
  config.numbers do |test_meta|
    case test_meta[:mode]
    when :chain
      (softbin * 10) + bin
    when :jtag
      (softbin * 20) + bin
    else
      (softbin * 30) + bin
    end
  end
end
```

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question. My first ever at stackoverflow, hope it makes sense. Feel free to email me if you have more questions.

@rchitect-of-info Yes, you can. Few changes will be required to the test_ids plugin to support your needs.

Please look at the allocate method here in test_ids plugin:
https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids/blob/master/lib/test_ids/allocator.rb#L115

We will need to pass the options from the flow to the allocate_number method.

```
number['number'] ||= allocate_number(bin: bin['number'], softbin: softbin['number'], size: number_size, options: options)
number['size'] ||= number_size
```

Then, please look at the allocate_number method here in the test_ids plugin:

https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids/blob/master/lib/test_ids/allocator.rb#L547

These callback options are what gets passed to config.numbers.

To access your metadata you would just pass the options along with bin and softbin here:

https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids/blob/master/lib/test_ids/allocator.rb#L548

So the new callback would be

```
  elsif callback = config.numbers.callback
    callback.call(bin, softbin, options)
```

You would then be able to configure TestIds as

```
TestIds.configure :final_test do |config|
  config.numbers do |bin, softbin, options|
   case options[:mode]
   when :chain
    (softbin * 10) + bin
   when :jtag
    (softbin * 20) + bin
   else
    (softbin * 30) + bin
   end
  end
 end
```

I am working on a similar update to test_ids, hopefully will be ready for review soon. My branch is currently a work in progress at https://github.com/priyavadan/test_ids/commits/change_config

Comment: Is there a way to get the options available in the |config, options| as well?  I need to be able to set the bin based on options metadata as well.

Comment: No, TestIds.configure is executed only once at the start of the flow, not per test

Comment: @Ginty you don't have any binning that is dependent on the type of test?

Comment: @rchitect-of-info AFAIK not yet, I am partially introducing that concept in our latest product application where the bins are assigned based on the type of test and each hard bin assignment has a range of soft bins associated with it.

Comment: @rchitect-of-info, we mainly use Origen to create IP-level test flows, which then get combined together elsewhere into a top-level flow. So within these IP level flows, we generally don't have assignments per test-type, rather we have a range allocated to testing the particular IP.
Having said that, I just remembered that we had a PR a while back that may have added support along the lines of what you want, but I don't know the details - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids/pull/2